# parallelize bash script that calls multiple files and uses bcp

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have the following:

```
        # **************************************************
        # **************************************************
        user=$(awk -F"[=;]" '/UID/{ print $2 }' file0.txt)
        pass=$(awk -F"[=;]" '/PWD/{ print $2 }' file0.txt)

        if [ $# -eq 0 ]
        then
            printf "we are deploying on **** for all metrics"
            (for status in status1 status2 status3
            do
                (for metric in metric1 metric2 metric3
                do 
                    (ipython file1.py Inpatient $status $metric
                    ipython file2.py Inpatient $status $metric
                    BCP table in output_Inpatient_$status_$metric.csv -U $user  -P $pass -t ',' -q -c
                    rm output_Inpatient_$status_$metric.csv) &
                done) &
                wait
            done

            ipython file3.py
            BCP table in output_2.csv -U $user -P $pass -t ',' -q -c 
            rm output_2.csv)

            (for status in status4 status5 status6
            do
                (for metric in metric4 metric5 metric6 
                do 
                    ipython file1.py Claims $status $metric
                    ipython file2.py Claims $status $metric
                    BCP table in output_Inpatient_$status_$metric.csv -U $user -P $pass -t ',' -q -c
                    rm output_Inpatient_$status_$metric.csv) &
                done) &
            done) )&    
        fi
```

I have a few questions. Is it possible to run the first and second set of for loops at the same time (parallel). Additionally, is it possible to run every combination of the set of for loops at the same time? i.e. parallelize each step of the above to run simultaneously? (they all write to the same csv name and they all bcp into the same table.. is that a problem?)

Comment: What is `BCP` please? Why do you `ipython` twice everywhere but with the same parameters? Where do you set `statuses`? And `metrics`?

Comment: those are all dummy variables I just made up when writing the question. Ipython calls two files. Status and metrics are defined in the loop. - Edited it to be a little less confusing. Status/metrics in the first for loop have to do with the Inpatient variable. second for loop have to do with the "Claims" metric

Comment: Oh and BCP is "bulk copy program" a way of sending data to microsoft sql server

Comment: Is this running under Windows or something? How do you have `bash` and Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: using git bash.

Comment: Is this running under Windows? Why have you omitted the shebang at the start of the script? Why is everything so evasive?

Comment: This is just one part of a much larger script. It is the part that I want to parallelize

Comment: Put any part of your script in a subshell with parenthesis, and you can background that section by putting a `&` after the close paren. Put each loop in a different backgrounded subshell, put a `wait` command afterwards to block until they're both done, and there you are.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help if you don't answer me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got it to run both sets (claims and Inpatient) of the for loops with this. What if I wanted to parallel each of the iterations in the for loop (i.e. status1/metric1, status1/metric2, status1/metric3...etc within each of the for loops?) I changed the output csv to output_Inpatient_$status_$metric.csv so there wouldnt be interference when bcping one and removing another.

Comment: `for item in "${list[@]}"; do process "$item" & done` will run all the items at once. We already have duplicates in the knowledge base covering that (and variants that limit the number of concurrent processes, so you don't handle more than your system can handle).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks Charles, I got it working. Can you explain the necessity for the wait?

Comment: Without the `wait`, the script could just exit while the subprocesses are still running.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Got it. So I think I only need to wait between the file3.py, as that is the only part of the script that relies on the previous part?

Comment: `wait` whenever you want *all* previously-started subprocesses to finish before proceeding. (Alternately, you can track the PID of each individual subprocess and then `wait` for them one at a time to get the exit status of each, and find out if any failed).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the above seems to not wait for the first set of for loops to finish before running file3.py. Do you know why? It would also be great if the sets of for loops would run simultaneously, but doesn't seem to be doing that

Comment: The nested `(`s break things there. `wait` doesn't get grandchildren, only direct children -- which is to say, restructure so you aren't doing that. :)

Comment: Ahh good to know. I just removed that part and put it in another script, then created a new script that calls the above first then the second script. Thanks for the help Charles!